# Umbraco add linked from page @nodename as text input value on form

Tags: javascript, macros, umbraco, ascx

How can I add the linked from page @nodename as a text input value on my form?
The input will disabled, so that the user cannot change the text.

```
<input type="text" name="jobtitle" id="jobtitle" value="Job Title to be Prefilled here by linked from page @nodeName - Disabled field" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is razor? Try @Model.Name instead.

Comment: It's actually .ascx and Umbraco 4.7.1 so not using razor